# Stacked barchart google visualization in internet explorer 8 'null or not an object'

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, google-visualization

I'm having troubles getting a stacked barchart to work in IE8.

I have the following html:

```
<div
  class="chart"
  id="chart-stress_average"
  style="position: relative;"
  data-chart-name="stress_average"
  data-chart-chartType="BarChart"
  data-chart-drawer="google"
  data-chart-data='[["y",{"role":"annotation"},"t1","t2","t3","t4"],["label1",40,0,40,0,0],["label2","",5,45,45,5]]'
  data-chart-options='{"legend":{"position":"none"},"hAxis":{"viewWindow":{"min":1,"max":100},"ticks":{}},"colors":["#d8000c","#f08a24","#43ac6a","#215835"],"enableInteractivity":false,"isStacked":true}'>
</div>
```

I then have a simple javascript script:

```
(function(){

    //create our chart rendering functions
    var Charts = window.Charts = {

        "active" : {},

        "google" : {
            draw : function(el, chartData, chartOptions)
            {
                var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(el);

                var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(chartData);
                chart.draw(data, chartOptions);
                return chart;
            }
        },

        load : function(){
            var chartsToRender = document.querySelectorAll("div.chart");
            var size = chartsToRender.length;
            for ( var i = 0; i < size; i++ )
            {
                var el = chartsToRender[i];

                var chartDrawer = el.getAttribute('data-chart-drawer');
                var chartData = JSON.parse(el.getAttribute('data-chart-data'));
                var chartOptions = JSON.parse(el.getAttribute('data-chart-options'));

                //call the correct chart function
                var renderedChart = Charts[chartDrawer].draw(el, chartData, chartOptions);

                Charts.active[el.getAttribute('data-chart-name')] = renderedChart;
            }
        }
    }

    if ( document.querySelectorAll("div.chart").length > 0 )
    {
        //load google lib
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"], callback:Charts.load})}); 
    }

})();
```

Now, this works fine in al browsers except IE8. i get this very nice, no idea what it means error:

> 'this.Oi.0.v' is null or not an object

I also have another char on that page that does work:

```
<div
  class="chart"
  id="chart-stress_detail"
  style="position: relative;"
  data-chart-name="stress_detail"
  data-chart-chartType="BarChart" data-chart-drawer="google"
  data-chart-data='[["y","score"],["s1",0.817754],["s2",0.171682],["s3",-0.728266],["s4",-0.736139],["s5",-1.168017],["s6",0.582581],["s7",-0.8577],["s8",0.017162]]'
  data-chart-options='{"height":360,"legend":{"position":"none"},"hAxis":{"viewWindow":{"min":-3,"max":3},"ticks":[{"v":-1,"f":"l2"},{"v":1,"f":"l1"}]},"bar":{"groupWidth":"90%"},"colors":["#4444a4"],"enableInteractivity":true}'
</div>
```

Any ideas why the second Is working and the first is not? :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect your problem is in your data:

```
[
    ["y",{"role":"annotation"},"t1","t2","t3","t4"],
    ["label1",40,0,40,0,0],
    ["label2","",5,45,45,5]
]
```

Your second column (the `annotation` role column) has a number in the first row of data and a string in the second.  The `arrayToDataTable` method detects column type by the data type of the first cells in the first row (unless specified in the header row), and so it is creating a `number` type column.  If I'm right, putting quotes around the `40` in the first row of data should fix this:

```
[
    ["y",{"role":"annotation"},"t1","t2","t3","t4"],
    ["label1","40",0,40,0,0],
    ["label2","",5,45,45,5]
]
```

**[Edit: found cause of error]**

The cause of the error is the `hAxis.ticks` option.  This option takes an array, but you specified an empty object.  It should be:

```
"ticks":[]
```

Comment: This would supprise me since it works in all other browsers/versions. it's just IE8 that's giving the troubles :( I tested it it with the quotes, and even added some text to the labels to no avail :(

Comment: Found it!  You specified the `hAxis.ticks` option as an object, when it should be an array: `"ticks":[]`.